# Php cannot decode Json with string backward slash

Tags: php

The string `{"foo":"\\"}` is valid json, but it seems that php cannot json decode it.

Running the following in php:

```
php > $a = '{"foo":"\\"}';
php > var_dump(json_decode($a));
php shell code:1:
NULL
php > var_dump(json_last_error_msg());
php shell code:1:
string(53) "Control character error, possibly incorrectly encoded"
```

What's happening here?

Comment: Having JSON, and having JSON *as a PHP string literal* are two different things…

Comment: Why are you creating JSON by hand in the first place? Use `json_encode()` and you'll always get a valid value.

Comment: I'm not creating it by hand, but retrieving it via an API

Comment: So you only have it for testing as a literal in your code? Then all problems will go away if you use the JSON retrieved via the API, instead of the literal. Just copy-pasting an arbitrary string into PHP source code doesn't necessarily work, since you need to take care to escape the string correctly as a string literal.

Comment: php should be able to decode received a string such as `{"foo":"\\"}`. Are you **sure** that the double backslash is the cause of the error ?

Answer (score 4):

`{"foo":"\\"}` is indeed a valid JSON, but in php, to have this string, you need to escape the `\` first.

```
$a = '{"foo":"\\\\"}';
var_dump($a);
echo "-------" . PHP_EOL;
var_dump(json_decode($a));
```

**Output**

```
string(12) "{"foo":"\\"}"
-------
object(stdClass)#1 (1) {
  ["foo"]=>
  string(1) "\"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to escape the backslash, because the PHP string parser is processing it as an escape.

```
$a = '{"foo":"\\\\"}';
```

But the right solution is to use `json_encode()`:

```
$a = json_encode(["foo": '\\']);
```

Notice that I had to escape the backslash in that literal.